# MySQL / phpMyadmin: "many connection errors"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My app no longer connects to its DB and phpmyadmin says #1129 - Host 'xxx.xx.xx.xx' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'

mysql_error() prints out the same message. Could this be because of too many connections?

What causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/blocked-host.html

> The number of interrupted connect
>   requests allowed is determined by the
>   value of the max_connect_errors system
>   variable. After max_connect_errors
>   failed requests, mysqld assumes that
>   something is wrong (for example, that
>   someone is trying to break in), and
>   blocks the host from further
>   connections until you execute a
>   mysqladmin flush-hosts command or
>   issue a FLUSH HOSTS  statement. See
>   Section 5.1.3, “Server System
>   Variables”.

You could be having network problems connecting to your database.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open a command prompt (or shell in Linux) with administrative privilleges
2. Flush all hosts in MySQL using mysqladmin:

   **mysqladmin flush-hosts -u root -p**
3. Open my.cnf (Linux) or my.ini (Windows) and change max_connect_errors variable to a large number. I used:

   **max_connect_errors= 1000000**
4. Restart MySQL server

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem when using monit to monitor our DB server. Monit will cause connection errors if your config is of the form:

```
if failed port 3306 with timeout 15 seconds 2 times within 3 cycles then alert
```

Rather than

```
if failed port 3306 protocol mysql with timeout 15 seconds 2 times within 3 cycles then alert
```

The lack of 'protocol mysql' causes the connection error count to notch up.